# How to trigger PHP-CI webhook manually aside from pushing

Tags: php, php-ci

does anyone know how to trigger the PHP-CI webhook manually?

cause I wanted it to connect to Hipchat Integration.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to trigger a webhook is built as follows:
`PHPCI_URL/webhook/git/PROJECT_ID`

As answer you should receive a JSON response as follows:
`{"status":"ok","buildID":"7"}`

Keep in mind you'll just be queueing a build, it will not do the build.

Comment: Im using it for bitbucket it doesn't work. you need to damn push something just to trigger it

Comment: {
"status": "failed",
"commits": []
}